# Re-arrange lists of lists in python

Tags: python, function, loops, nested-lists

I need to turn this lists of lists into the following format.
I accomplished this by creating a function and creating 4 additional lists to split the data into the required format.
I was wondering if this could resolved in a simpler way.

The code I wrote is at the end.

Thanks.

```
vals = [ [1,  2,  3,  4],
         [5,  6,  7,  8],
         [9 , 10, 11, 12],
         [13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24],
         [25, 26, 27, 28],
         [29, 30, 31, 32],
         [33, 34, 35, 36]]
```

This needs to be converted to column format as such:

```
out = [[ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36]]
```

```
def all_list(value):
    result = {}
    amount = []
    duration = []
    rate = []
    down_payment = []
    headers = parse_headers(file1[0])
    total = [amount, duration, rate, down_payment]
    for v in range(0,len(value)):
        amount.append(value[v][0])
        duration.append(value[v][1])
        rate.append(value[v][2])
        down_payment.append(value[v][3])
    for k,v in zip(total, headers):
        result[v] = k
    return result
```

Comment: Can't you rewrite your question with more user friendly number that follow a more logical pattern so the transform is easier to see

Comment: Sorry for that, will be careful in the future. I just started learning python a month ago on my own. Still new to this.

Comment: Yea, using number like ```values = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]``` will make it easier for people to visualise your question. Goodluck learning python. I will edit this question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to transpose the 2-dimensional list. Here is an implementation to this.

```
def transpose(l1):
    l2 = []
    for i in range(len(l1[0])):
        row =[]
        for item in l1:
            row.append(item[i])
        l2.append(row)
    return l2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with the `*` operator:

```
>>> values = [[100000.0, 36.0, 0.08, 20000.0],
...  [200000.0, 12.0, 0.1, 0.0],
...  [628400.0, 120.0, 0.12, 100000.0],
...  [4637400.0, 240.0, 0.06, 0.0],
...  [42900.0, 90.0, 0.07, 8900.0],
...  [916000.0, 16.0, 0.13, 0.0],
...  [45230.0, 48.0, 0.08, 4300.0],
...  [991360.0, 99.0, 0.08, 0.0],
...  [423000.0, 27.0, 0.09, 47200.0]]
>>> list(zip(*values))
[(100000.0, 200000.0, 628400.0, 4637400.0, 42900.0, 916000.0, 45230.0, 991360.0, 423000.0), (36.0, 12.0, 120.0, 240.0, 90.0, 16.0, 48.0, 99.0, 27.0), (0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.06, 0.07, 0.13, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09), (20000.0, 0.0, 100000.0, 0.0, 8900.0, 0.0, 4300.0, 0.0, 47200.0)]
```

If it's important to have the new list be of lists instead of tuples, map `list` over it:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*values)))
[[100000.0, 200000.0, 628400.0, 4637400.0, 42900.0, 916000.0, 45230.0, 991360.0, 423000.0], [36.0, 12.0, 120.0, 240.0, 90.0, 16.0, 48.0, 99.0, 27.0], [0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.06, 0.07, 0.13, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09], [20000.0, 0.0, 100000.0, 0.0, 8900.0, 0.0, 4300.0, 0.0, 47200.0]]
```

Comment: This works but it returns the list of lists as tuple instead of list.

Comment: Just map `list` over it then (note that it's only important for it to be a list if you intend to mutate it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a more concise way of doing it using comprehensions:

```py
amount = [item[0] for item in value]
duration = [item[1] for item in value]
rate = [item[2] for item in value]
down_payment = [item[3] for item in value]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a matrix transpose. Numpy has this built in like this

```
import numpy as np
ans = np.transpose(values)
```

Comment: This works great but the result is showing 'ndarray' next to the list.

{'amount': array([ 100000.,  200000.,  628400., 4637400.,   42900.,  916000.,45230.,  991360.,  423000.])

is there a way around this?

Comment: @AliNaveed does it show that when you print? If you don't need to manipulate it as an array after the transpose then you can just convert it to a list using ```ans = list(ans)```

Comment: When I use it within the function and return the print, it's showing there. I tried converting it back but its till the same.